# Introducing RC Filter to reduce noise

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, remote-control

I have designed a constant current circuit using an opamp.
[image]

If I want to implement an RC filter to reduce the noise, where can I add?

Option1: I am planning to add between the inverting terminal and ground, which is parallel to 281 ohm.

Option 2: I have read through some documents and found that if add it across the voltage divider circuit, I can reduce the noise from the supply before amplification. But I am confused regarding that.

Could anyone explain me which of the above options is best? Regarding the 2nd option, I am not sure.

Please spare me if I am wrong, as I dont have much knowledge in analog electronics.

Edit1:

The current is varying slightly. I have added the current values with respect to the time.

[image]

Comment: What noise and one which node do you want to reduce?

Comment: @Andyaka: The current value is fluctuating with time. I want to reduce this fluctuation as far as possible. I have added the variation in the post. I am not sure about the node. I dont know whether the noise is coming from which node.

Comment: Start with a capacitor from +12V to ground close to the Vcc input pin and one from + to ground.

Comment: What op-amp? What type resistors? What is the 12V source, is it accurate? Note you're using 12V as a reference, and any variation in it is reflected precisely in the output.

Comment: @TimWilliams: OPamp is LM324N.
Used fixed value resistors (colour coded one).
I have used GW Instek PPE-3323 is a 3-channel, programmable linear DC power supply. 
https://www.batterfly.com/shop/en/gw-instek-ppe-3323
The supply is fixed but I am not sure whether the ac mains have an effect on it

Comment: There are over a dozen types of "color coded" resistors, could you be more specific (carbon comp, carbon film, metal film, metal oxide...)? The supply claims 2mV noise, which sounds like a smoking gun here. Why not measure the 12V supply in the same way you measured the output? And for completeness -- what are you measuring with anyway?

Comment: @winny: From positive to  ground will be parallel to the second 6.8k resistor. 
Is it like i should keep a capacitor across both voltage divider circuit as a whole?

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am using a carbon film resistor. I am measuring with a Fluke 8845 DMM.
https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/precision-measurement/bench-instruments/fluke-8845a-8846a

Comment: You want to decouple every DC voltage with a capacitor. Also, replace the bottom 6.8 kohm with a Zener diode.

Comment: The LM324 is The Noisiest opamp ever made which is why it is never used for audio. Use a modern low noise audio opamp instead and add a 100uF capacitor to ground from the +input of the opamp to ground. The three unused opamps might be oscillating so disable them.

Answer (score 0):

The filter can be added somewhere in the feedback loop, the problem is this can make the loop unstable especially if the RC pole is placed close to the opamps poles. It's best to simulate and do an AC analysis, make sure there are no "peaks" in the gain of the circuit

Comment: is the Feedback loop means parallel to the laser diode? I should add a resistor and capacitor parallel to the diode which is at the output of the opamp?
Or can I place a capacitor parallel to the 281ohm resistor?

Comment: An RC filter between the load and the negative terminal if the op anamp would be a good start